# ASP.NET MVC : maximum request length exceeded despite maxRequestLength maxAllowedContentLength set in web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, content-length, maxrequestlength

I've been trying to upload a file larger than 4mb to an ASP.NET MVC web application (for a long time) and I've looked at so many stack exchange articles so I am aware this is a duplicate, but I've tried everything I'm not making any progress.

I'm running Visual Studio 2019 16.3.9 / IISExpress 10.0 / .NET 4.5.2.

The following code has been added

```
<location path="UploadedAudio">
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="3600" maxRequestLength="1048576" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Things I've tried to resolve the issue:

- adding the above code to all of the below files (individually & all together) -

  ```
  ~/View/web.config
  ~/web.Debug.config
  ~/web.config
  ```
- I've tried this without `<location>`.
- Windows features - Request Filtering on - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits/
- From what I've read it's means to be in - 'View/web.config'
- I've read that adding the above code to the following file could work:

  ```
  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\web.config
  ```
- Setting `maxRequestLength` lower than `maxAllowedContentLength`

But nothing seems to work for me. Are there any considerations for running in debug mode in Visual Studio that I'm missing?

Any help would or corrections would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: add only in the single web config file of the project and try

Comment: Which file are you referring to? I've tried adding it to each of the files I mentioned above individually.

Comment: You may need to refresh/reset something that is cached.  Resetting iis, deleting obj/bin directories, reentering Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I had to copy this -
`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\web.config`

edit it with the `maxRequestLength` and `maxAllowedContentLength`

then copy the file back into the directory.